# is there an 'execute' statement in python?

Tags: python

Is there such a thing in python as an 'execute' statement that I can use similarly to the way I have below?

```
statement='print "hello world"'

def loop(statement):
    for i in range(100):
        for j in range(100):
            execute statement

loop(statement)
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, simply pass a *callable* and use `statement()` to execute it.

A *callable* is a function, lambda expression or any other object that implements [`__call__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__).

```
def loop(func):
    for i in range(100):
        for j in range(100):
            func()

def say_hello():
    print "hello world"
loop(say_hello)
```

If you really want to execute code from a string (trust me, you don't!), there is [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec):

```
>>> code = 'print "hello bad code"'
>>> exec code
hello bad code
```

Comment: find another name for the statement function or it will be difficult for non-initiated pythonists to understand the difference with your callable argument in loop

Comment: Now it should be more obvious

Comment: functions *are* objects and they have `__call__` attribute.

Comment: why is it bad to execute code from a string? Using exec is a more brief way of doing it.

Comment: @fergusdawson: it is much slower to execute, and if used in conjunction with user input can allow code injection attacks.

Comment: Is there any way in the example above that func() can access i and j in the enclosing function? When i try to reference the i in loop from func I get a global name not defined error.

Comment: @fergusdawson, yes there is, but I'd encourage you to find a way to not need `exec`

Comment: @fergusdawson: Why can't you pass them to the function as arguments? `func(i, j)` and `def say_hello(i, j): print 'hello world %d %d' % (i, j)`

Comment: @thiefmaster of course, that should have been obvious. thanks

Comment: Great, if everything is solved please do not forget to accept the answer by clicking the gray checkmark icon on the left below the vote buttons.